# Why is the CORS error still appearing after enabling CORS in NodeJS app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

When I try to send some input from my form to my react backend, it prompts the CORS error even if I have CORS used in the server.js file. I have attached and image from the front-end and from the back-end

[image]

[image]

handleSubmit from my react app

```
   handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('Registration form was submitted');
    console.log(this.state.fullname +' '+ this.state.age+' '+ this.state.adress)
    fetch('https://localhost:4000/regUser', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            name: this.state.fullname,
            age: this.state.age,
            adress: this.state.adress
        })
    }).then( res => res.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data))
}
```

Comment: Your error isn't actually related to CORS, no such route exists. Check the error in the network tab.

Comment: Your node server is not configured for https. Change `fetch('https://..` to `fetch('http://..`

Comment: [Please see why we shouldn't post images of text :)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1):

This the CORS error is misleading in some cases.
And your case is one of those cases.

You are calling a post request on route `/regUser` but you are listening for get request on your server :

Change your server code to :

```js
app.post("/regUser",(req,res)=>{
    let data=req.body;
    return res.send(data);
}
```

Note : As you are accessing req.body I have assumed that you want to use post in other cases just make sure you are sending and listening for same kind of request.

And as pointed in comments your server is not configured for `https` so use `http` instead.